# Command assists for Texworks

Tags: windows, editors, texworks, kile

Are the following features of Kile available in texworks or any other tex-editors for windows ?

1. Any word or command used before, appearing as options automatically after typing the first three letters of it.
2. Appearance of list of the used citekeys and references, after adding \cite{} and 
   \ref{} resp.
3. Frequently used math symbols, appearing by the side of the opened tex file.
4. Keeping backup.
5. Spelling checks.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Kile provides these features and is a TeX editor for Windows (and other operating systems).

Comment: for texmaker: 1) no, 2) may be, not sure, some thing like that exist for label-ref exist, 3)+4)+5) yes.

Comment: TeXworks only has 5), I think.

Comment: @cfr Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician not much of an answer ....

Comment: @cfr Thanks, it actually is the best match, so it is an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As you say, Kile offers these features. Moreover, Kile is a TeX editor for Windows (and other platforms).